# Destroying units due to a crisis card

Tags: xcom

In a game of Xcom: The Board Game, a crisis card came up that said we needed to destroy two interceptors.

Can I destroy the interceptors from the reserves or do they need to be destroyed from the board?

Please note that I am **not** referring to the recruitment pool of units

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither the FAQ nor the rules seem to address this directly, but lacking a specific ruling I would say that you can lose them from either reserves or the board.  If they had specifically wanted you to lose ones from the board, the card would've said so (like the one that says that you lose a soldier on the mission, rather than just saying lose a soldier).